# Proving inequality using AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Question:

$ Suppose\ x,\ y\ are\ positive\ real\ numbers.\ Show\ that\ \left(x^2-y^2\ \right)\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\ge 0 $

My attempt:

[image]

I tried proving it using AM-GM inequality. Is my approach correct? If not, how can I prove it using AM-GM inequality?

Comment: The square of any real number is non-negative, so I don't see why you need to prove that $(x-y)^2 \ge 0\,$.

Comment: So the work you went through using AM-GM is actually how the inequality is typically proved. $(x-y)^2$ is always a positive quantity, so you can just use this fact without appealing to AM-GM

Comment: I understand that it is obvious but I how do I formally explain my steps?

Comment: At the level where you know and are allowed to use AM-GM, I presume you don't need a proof that $z^2 \ge 0\,$ for all $\,\forall z \in \mathbb{R}\,$.

Comment: What about (x + y) / xy

Comment: How do I prove or explain that

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel If you really *have* to prove that the product and ratio of two positive numbers are positive, then you'll have to go back to the first principles, starting with how multiplication and division are defined in the reals.

Comment: I dont think I am required to do that. I think I can just explain in plain English that the product of two positive real numbers is more than or equal to zero. Similar explanation for addition.

Comment: I was just curious because I recently learned about AM-GM inequality so I was wondering that might apply to this question

Answer (score 1):

It's just
$$\frac{(x-y)^2(x+y)}{xy}\geq0$$

Comment: That's what the OP wrote, but tried to *prove* $(x-y)^2 \ge 0$ with AM-GM.

Comment: @dxiv I did not see it. Now I see that AM-GM here it's not necessary.

Comment: Could you start from the beginning and explain your steps? Thanks.

Comment: @Josh Mitkitzel Now I see that you got it in your seventh line.

Comment: Do you think thats a good enough explanation?

Comment: Should I add any further explanations?

Comment: @Josh Mitkitzel I think you solution in the seventh line is enough and very well.

Answer (score 1):

If $x = y$, the inequality holds.

If $y > x$, then $x^2 < y^2$ (hence $x^2 - y^2 < 0$) and $1/y < 1/x $ (hence $1/y - 1/x < 0$)  and the inequality holds.

Do the same for $y < x$.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you show me some steps?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel You have a product of the numbers $x^2 - y^2$ and $1/y - 1/x$, and you must show that the product is not smaller than $0$. This will be true if both terms are $ > 0$ or both terms are $<0$ or at least one of the terms $= 0$.